# How to check when date is valid, do A, else do B in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a query that shows data that looks like this

Note that the data is used for attendance report
Input Data:

| name | datefrom | dateto | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | 01-11-2022 | - | 1 |
| Beth | 01-11-2022 | 03-11-2022 | 2 |
| Casey | 01-11-2022 | - | 1 |
| Andy | 02-11-2022 | - | 1 |
| Casey | 02-11-2022 | - | 1 |

...

| Name | 01 | 02 | ... | 31 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | yes | yes | ... | X | 8 |
| Beth | leave | leave | ... | X | 5 |
| Casey | yes | yes | ... | X | 7 |

(Total attendance/ "yes" in a month)

My problem is that some months has 30 days, some 31, or even 28/ 29

I manually selected the data, like so...

```sql
select user_fullname as usrname,
nvl(
    max(CASE WHEN to_char(datefrom,'dd') = '01' and status = 1 THEN 'yes' else 'no' end END)
,'-') as "01",
```

and so on...

and I've tried

```
case when to_date('01-11-2022','dd-mm-yyyy')-to_date('01-12-2022','dd-mm-yyyy') = 30
then 
nvl(
    max(CASE WHEN to_char(datefrom,'dd') = '31' and status = 1 THEN 'yes' else 'no' end END)
,'-') 
else 'X' end as "31",
```

but it shows an invalid date error because apparently SQL validates all the codes even if it would be skipped (assuming that the case statement would return false)

Can someone give me an idea to resolve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Could you please show some sample input data and the expected outcome? Better for more than just one row.

Comment: Your 1st code looks OK to me; you'd "repeat" that 31 times (as there are MAX 31 days in a month) to create 31 columns. What difference does it make whether certain month has less than 31 days? That TO_CHAR function doesn't care about it. So - what's the problem you're trying to solve? Also, +1 to what Jonas said.

Comment: I have edited the data like you asked. As for @Littlefoot, the TO_CHAR function does care when I wrote TO_CHAR('31-11-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') because I used it to check whether the person is on leave

Comment: ```nvl(max(CASE WHEN to_char(datefrom,'dd') = '30' or ((datefrom<=to_date('30-11-2022','dd-mm-yyyy') and dateto>=to_date('30-11-2022','dd-mm-yyyy')) and status=2) THEN case when status != 2 then 'yes' else status end END),'-') as "30",
```

Answer (score 0):

From your data i understood you want to put X for months which doesn't have those dates.

```
 CASE WHEN last_day(datefrom) < 29 THEN 'X' ELSE --your original condition
 As "29"
 CASE WHEN last_day(datefrom) < 30 THEN 'X' ELSE --your original condition
 As "30"
 CASE WHEN last_day(datefrom) < 31 THEN 'X' ELSE --your original condition
 As "31"
```

Comment: this might work, I'm getting this error tho ```ORA-00937: not a single-group group function```

Comment: show me your SQL

Comment: use 'group by user_fullname'

Comment: I've already used group by user_fullname and total

Comment: why are you using MAX ??

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```sql
WITH           -- sample data
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 'Andy' "USER_FULL_NAME", To_Date('01.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DATE_FROM", 1 "STATUS" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 'Andy', To_Date('02.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 'Andy', To_Date('04.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 'Andy', To_Date('05.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 'Andy', To_Date('12.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ID", 'Andy', To_Date('21.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Rick', To_Date('02.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Rick', To_Date('09.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Rick', To_Date('10.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Rick', To_Date('12.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Rick', To_Date('28.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Rick', To_Date('31.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", 'Beth', To_Date('01.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 2 From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", 'Beth', To_Date('05.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 From Dual 
        ),
--
    days AS (  Select LPAD(LEVEL, 2, '0') "DAY_NO" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 31  )
--
SELECT  ID, USER_FULL_NAME, MONTH , 
        Nvl("'01'", 'x') "'01'", Nvl("'02'", 'x') "'02'", Nvl("'03'", 'x') "'03'", Nvl("'04'", 'x') "'04'", Nvl("'05'", 'x') "'05'", Nvl("'06'", 'x') "'06'",
        Nvl("'07'", 'x') "'07'", Nvl("'08'", 'x') "'08'", Nvl("'09'", 'x') "'09'", Nvl("'10'", 'x') "'10'", Nvl("'11'", 'x') "'11'", Nvl("'12'", 'x') "'12'",
        Nvl("'13'", 'x') "'13'", Nvl("'14'", 'x') "'14'", Nvl("'15'", 'x') "'15'", Nvl("'16'", 'x') "'16'", Nvl("'17'", 'x') "'17'", Nvl("'18'", 'x') "'18'",
        Nvl("'19'", 'x') "'19'", Nvl("'20'", 'x') "'20'", Nvl("'21'", 'x') "'21'", Nvl("'22'", 'x') "'22'", Nvl("'23'", 'x') "'23'", Nvl("'24'", 'x') "'24'",
        Nvl("'25'", 'x') "'25'", Nvl("'26'", 'x') "'26'", Nvl("'27'", 'x') "'27'", Nvl("'28'", 'x') "'28'", Nvl("'29'", 'x') "'29'", Nvl("'30'", 'x') "'30'",  Nvl("'31'", 'x') "'31'",
        TOTAL
FROM    ( Select  t.ID,   -- this subquery defines conditions and the data for pivoting
                  t.USER_FULL_NAME,
                  To_Char(t.DATE_FROM, 'MON-yyyy') "MONTH",
                  CASE t.STATUS WHEN 1 THEN 'yes' WHEN 0 THEN 'no' WHEN 2 THEN 'leave' ELSE 'x' END "DAY_STAT",   -- here you can make any other condition that you need to define status
                  Sum(CASE t.STATUS WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID, To_Char(t.DATE_FROM, 'MON-yyyy')) "TOTAL",
                  d.DAY_NO
          From  tbl t
          Inner Join  days d ON(d.DAY_NO = To_Char(t.DATE_FROM, 'dd'))
        ) 
    PIVOT ( Max(DAY_STAT)
            FOR DAY_NO IN('01','02','03','04','05','06','07', '08', '09', '10',
                          '11','12','13','14','15','16','17', '18', '19', '20',
                          '21','22','23','24','25','26','27', '28', '29', '30', '31') 
          )
```

R e s u l t :  (you can filter it with Where clause to get just one user and/or month of interest)

```sql
/*
        ID USER_FULL_NAME MONTH    '01'  '02'  '03'  '04'  '05'  '06'  '07'  '08'  '09'  '10'  '11'  '12'  '13'  '14'  '15'  '16'  '17'  '18'  '19'  '20'  '21'  '22'  '23'  '24'  '25'  '26'  '27'  '28'  '29'  '30'  '31'       TOTAL
---------- -------------- -------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----------
         1 Andy           DEC-2022 yes   yes   x     yes   no    x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x              3 
         1 Andy           NOV-2022 x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     no    x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     yes   x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x              1 
         2 Rick           DEC-2022 x     no    x     x     x     x     x     x     yes   yes   x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     no    x     x     yes            3 
         2 Rick           NOV-2022 x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     no    x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x              0 
         3 Beth           NOV-2022 leave x     x     x     yes   x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x     x              1 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data(usrname, datefrom) as (
    select 'Andy', to_date('01-01-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'Andy', to_date('02-01-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'Andy', to_date('03-01-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'Andy', to_date('30-01-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'Andy', to_date('02-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual -- union all
),
doms(d) as (
    select level from dual connect by level <= 31
)
select *
from (
    select usrname, to_char(ym,'YYYY-MM') as ym, d.d as dom,
        nvl2(dom,'yes',case when d.d > to_number(to_char(add_months(ym,1)-1,'DD')) then 'X' else 'no' end) as present
    from doms d
    left outer join (
        select usrname, trunc(datefrom,'MM') as ym, to_number(to_char(datefrom,'DD')) as dom
        from data) dat 
    partition by (dat.usrname, dat.ym)
    on d.d = dom
)
pivot (
    max(present) for dom in (
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
    )
)
;


USRN YM      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31 
---- ------- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
Andy 2022-01 yes yes yes no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  yes no 
Andy 2022-02 no  yes no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  no  X   X   X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a calendar and use a partitioned outer join to the table and then pivot:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT m.month,
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM c.day) AS day,
         t.name,
         COALESCE(t.status, 1) AS status
  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(datefrom, 'MM') AS month FROM table_name) m
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT m.month + LEVEL - 1 AS day
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY m.month + LEVEL - 1 < ADD_MONTHS(month, 1)
         ) c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
         PARTITION BY (t.name)
         ON ( c.day BETWEEN t.datefrom AND COALESCE(t.dateto, t.datefrom) )
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(status) FOR day IN (
     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
    11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
    21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
    31
  )
)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name, datefrom, dateto, status) AS
SELECT 'Andy',  DATE '2022-11-01', NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beth',  DATE '2022-11-01', DATE '2022-11-03', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Casey', DATE '2022-11-01', NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Andy',  DATE '2022-11-02', NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Casey', DATE '2022-11-02', NULL, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MONTH | NAME | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-NOV-22 | Andy | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | *null* |
| 01-NOV-22 | Beth | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | *null* |
| 01-NOV-22 | Casey | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | *null* |

*Note: if you want to map from numeric statuses to tables you can include a join to a table with the mappings or use a `CASE` expression or the `DECODE` function.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M1vw-DhH)